# можно пример к этой части кода или полностью(расширение_$f_есть_txt)

Tags: php

можно пример к этой части кода или полностью(расширение_$f_есть_txt)

```
unset($FNames); // на всякий случай стираем массив
while ($f = очередное_имя_файла_в_текущем каталоге)
if (расширение_$f_есть_txt) $FNames[] = $f;
// теперь $FNames содержит список файлов с расширением txt

можно пример 
расширение_$f_есть_txt)
```

Comment: проверьте 4 последних символа в имени: `if (substr($f, -4) === '.txt') {`

Comment: `$files = glob("./*.txt")` возьмите и не надо тестировать ничего

Comment: $files = glob("./*.txt");
echo "$files";
( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/php.xxx/1/arrays/foreach_ref.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  393600  {main}( )   .../foreach_ref.php:0
Array

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [Документации pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php)

```
    unset($FNames);
    while ($f = очередное_имя_файла_в_текущем каталоге) {
        $info = pathinfo(__DIR__ . $f);
        if (isset($info['extension']) && $info['extension'] == 'txt') $FNames[] = $f;
    }
```

Comment: <?php ## Слияние списков при помощи оператора +.
unset($FNames);
while ($f = 1.txt) {
  $info = pathinfo(__DIR__ . $f);
  if (isset($info['extension']) && $info['extension'] == 'txt') $FNames[] = $f;
}
?>
 
 
 
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'txt' (T_STRING) in /var/www/php.xxx/1/arrays/badplus.php on line 3

Comment: При создании цикла возьмите название файла в ковычки. `<?php ## Слияние списков при помощи оператора +. unset($FNames); while ($f = '1.txt') { $info = pathinfo(DIR . $f); if (isset($info['extension']) && $info['extension'] == 'txt') $FNames[] = $f; } ?> `

Comment: а почему пустой экран после этого?

Comment: Так вы же ничего не выводите на экран. Воспользуйтесь var_dump($FNames);

Comment: unset($FNames); while ($f = '1.txt') { $info = pathinfo(_DIR_ . $f); if (isset($info['extension']) && $info['extension'] == 'txt') $FNames[] = $f; }
var_dump($FNames);
пустой экран

Comment: Так у Вас точно есть в папке с этим файлом( в котором вы работаете), файл с именем 1.txt?

Comment: есть моя цель научиться

Comment: Тогда еще, подскажите, зачем вы используете while?

Comment: потому что так в книге написано. Я хочу все понять

Comment: Так вы начинайте читать и учить опираясь не только на книгу, но и на документацию, читайте о каждой функции и цикле. Цикл while будет выполняться каждый раз, когда выражение внутри условия будет true. Сейчас у Вас в условии присваивание стоит, оно всегда будет true, по-этому цикл будет выполняться бесконечно.

Comment: Для простого условия вам здесь не нужен while.

Comment: `unset($FNames); 
$f = '1.txt';  $info = pathinfo(DIR . $f); if (isset($info['extension']) && $info['extension'] == 'txt') $FNames[] = $f; var_dump($FNames); `

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: FNames in /var/www/php.xxx/1/arrays/foreach_ref.php on line 8
Call Stack
#  Time  Memory  Function  Location
1  0.0001  395512  {main}( )  .../foreach_ref.php:0

Comment: Уберите строку с unset($FNames)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем уверен, но вроде бы то что Вам нужно делается так(один из вариантов):

```
$FNames = []; // на всякий случай стираем массив
while ($f = очередное_имя_файла_в_текущем каталоге)
$type = explode('.', $f);

if (array_pop($type) === 'txt') $FNames[] = $f;
```

**Недостатки и нюансы этого способа:**
1. Если файл не имеет расширения, название файла будет типом.
2. Проверка идет только по названию файла, лучше брать MIME-type
3. Нет проверки файл ли это или директория. Если список файлов генерируется с помощью функции `scandir()`, тогда название папки будет типом (Если в папке будет точка, будет браться последний фрагмент.

**Улучшенный вариант первого:**

```
$FNames = []; // на всякий случай стираем массив
while ($f = очередное_имя_файла_в_текущем каталоге)
$type = explode('.', $f);

if(sizeof($type) === 1){
   $type = '';
}else{
    $type = array_pop($type)
}
if ($type === 'txt') $FNames[] = $f;
```

**Недостатки и нюансы этого способа:**
1. Проверка идет только по названию файла, лучше брать MIME-type
2. Нет проверки файл ли это или директория. Если список файлов генерируется с помощью функции `scandir()`, тогда название папки может быть типом (Если в папке будет точка, будет браться последний фрагмент.

Comment: <?php ## Слияние списков при помощи оператора +.
$FNames = []; // на всякий случай стираем массив
while ($f = badplus)
$type = explode('.', $f);
if(sizeof($type) === 1){
  $type = '';
}else{
  $type = array_pop($type)
}
if ($type === 'txt') $FNames[] = $f;
?>
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /var/www/php.xxx/1/arrays/badplus.php on line 10